# VBA, worksheet.sort.apply method error

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, runtime-error

I am trying to sort a range.

`<edit>`
But I am getting an error message when the script(*below*) reaches the line with `.apply` near the end.

The error message is:

```
Run-time error '1004':

The sort reference is not valid.  
Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, 
and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank.
```

`</edit>`

`<edit>`
The range to be sorted is within a ***different*** workbook than the one that is calling the function **AND** defining the range to be sorted.
`</edit>`

Each column in this range is to be sorted, with column 1 being sorted first, then column 2, then comlumn 3...

The result being that any row with identical values in a column, are sorted further based on the proceeding columns

eg.

```
  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  
-----------------------
  3  |  9  |  4  |  1  
  4  |  5  |  7  |  7  
  4  |  5  |  3  |  4  
  4  |  1  |  9  |  2  
  2  |  6  |  3  |  8  
  4  |  5  |  3  |  1
```

becomes...

```
  A  |  B  |  C  |  D    
-----------------------
  2  |  6  |  3  |  8  
  3  |  9  |  4  |  1  
  4  |  1  |  9  |  2  
  4  |  5  |  3  |  1  
  4  |  5  |  3  |  4  
  4  |  5  |  7  |  7
```

I have the script as this so far:

```
Private Sub tableSort(ByRef rng As Range)

    If (rng.Rows.Count > 1) Then
        With rng.Parent.Sort

            With .SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add key:=rng, _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlAscending, _
                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal

                Dim iCounter As Integer
                For iCounter = 2 To rng.Columns.Count

                    .Add key:=Range( _
                            Cells( _
                                rng.Rows(1).Row, _
                                rng.Columns(iCounter).Column), _
                            Cells( _
                                rng.Rows(rng.Rows.Count).Row, _
                                rng.Columns(rng.Columns.Count).Column)) _
                        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                            Order:=xlAscending, _
                            DataOption:=xlSortNormal

                Next iCounter
            End With

            .SetRange rng
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply

            SendKeys "{ESC}"

        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

What i'm doing is first getting the total number of columns in the range object thats being passed in. Then I am adding a sort field for each column using a for loop. Then I am performing the sort.

```
Private Sub tableSort(ByRef rng As Range)
    Dim cols as Integer
    Dim curcol as Integer
    cols = rng.Columns.Count

    With rng.Parent
        For curcol = 1 To cols
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=rng.Columns(curcol), _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        Next curcol

        With .Sort
            .SetRange rng
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you should substitute `Worksheets("Sheet1")` with `rng.Parent` and be sure you're acting on the same worksheet the passed `rng` Range belongs to. Furthermore it's good practice using `Option Explicit` declaration on top of the module and hence adding `Dim cols As Long, curcol As Long` right after `Private Sub tableSort(ByRef rng As Range)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. (Both of you) 
@user3598756 ...
Option Explicit is at the top of the module. 
I tested your suggestion to use an explicit worksheet; same problem occurred though. 
I well add an edit to the post, but _perhaps it is worth noting_ that: the function call is within **1** worksheet and the range is constructed (on the **1** worksheet) for a **separate** worksheet.

Comment: Thank you @user3598756 for your suggestion!

Comment: My suggestions were on cullan's code, and I did _not_ suggest any explicit worksheet reference but the use of a range related one. As for your last comment: are you using the function as a UDF or is it called inside a macro sub?

Comment: @user3598756 the function exists within a macro sub

Comment: then then the provided solution should work. If you have issue, explain them in detail